# parse text and get number of hours

Tags: python, nltk

i have a pandas dataframe with text attribute as

```
loc_id   text
1        'Monday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Tuesday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Wednesday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Thursday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Friday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Saturday: Closed,Sunday: Closed'
2         ''
3         'Monday: Open 24 hours,Tuesday: Open 24 hours,Wednesday: Open 24 hours,Thursday: Open 24 hours,Friday: Open 24 hours,Saturday: Open 24 hours,Sunday: Open 24 hours
```

its a text data and i want to compute the total number of opening hours when it was open like this

```
loc_id      openingHours
1           45
2           NAN
3           168
```

i am new to text mining so have no idea how to parse and convert it.The text only have these two formats as mentioned.

Comment: Where does 45 hours come from? You might want to look into regexes, and the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: 45 hours comes by adding all the opening hours of the week.

Comment: Take a look at the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **working solution** specific to your problem!

Explanations given below.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
sumtime = 0
sumlist=[]
list_of_strings = ['''Monday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Tuesday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Wednesday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Thursday: 8:30 AM
\x96 5:30 PM,Friday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Saturday: Closed,Sunday: Closed''','''Monday: Open 24 hours,Tuesday: Open 24 hours,Wednesday: Open
24 hours,Thursday: Open 24 hours,Friday: Open 24 hours,Saturday: Open 24 hours,Sunday: Open 24 hours''']

for s in list_of_strings: #Text for each loc_id
    if 'Open' not in s:
     #If the word 'Open' isn't present in the text then do below
            times = [line[0] for line in re.findall(r'\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))',s)]
            times = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(times[0::2], times[1::2])]
            fmt = '%I:%M %p'
            time_objects = [datetime.strptime(b,fmt)-datetime.strptime(a,fmt)
                            for a,b in times]
            finaltime = [td.seconds//3600 for td in time_objects]
            sumtime=sum(finaltime)
            sumlist.append(sumtime)
    else:
    #If Open is present in the text 

            open_times = [int(st) for st in s.split() if st.isdigit()]
            sumlist.append(sum(open_times))
print(sumlist)
```

1) **re.findall** returns each and every match found in the string. It's ouput would be something like this

`[('8:30 AM', '8', '30', 'AM'),('5:30 PM', '5', '30', 'PM'), ('8:30 AM', '8', '30', 'AM')]`

Hence line[0] would give the first one from the tuple. i.e '8:30 AM' which we require

```
[line[0] for line in re.findall(r'\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))',s)]
```

2) The output of the above will be

```
['8:30 AM', '5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', '5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', '5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', '5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', '5:30 PM']
```

3) Now every even element (0,2,4,..) of the list will be paired with odd one (1,3,5,..). Note times[0::2] here gives a list of elements starting from **index 0** incrementing every index by **2**. Similarly starting from **index 1**
incrementing by **2**. And zip them together. You get this,

`[['8:30 AM', '5:30 PM'], ['8:30 AM', '5:30 PM'],...and so on]`

```
times = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(times[0::2], times[1::2])]
```

4) fmt is the **format** `fmt = '%I:%M %p'`. Note it would be %H:%M but since we are using %p
the documentation clearly specifies that in that case we should us %I instead of %H. Otherwise %H is fine. Use **datetime.strptime** on our a,b which is `[8:30 AM', '5:30 PM']` to get a datetime object. Subtract them to get a **timedelta** object. Convert it into seconds using `timdelta_object.seconds`.

```
 [datetime.strptime(b,fmt)-datetime.strptime(a,fmt) for a,b in times]
```

Then you can use `td.days` to get days , `td//3600` to get hours

5) Find the sum of this list using `sum(your_list)` to get the sum which is **45** in your case. Append that to a list.

6) If the word *Open* is present in your text,

then get the numbers alone from the text as int and find their sum.

7) Finally the output list would be

`[45, 168]`

This is a working solution to the problem you have in hand. Assuming you get text either in this format

```
'Monday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Tuesday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Wednesday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Thursday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Friday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Saturday: Closed,Sunday: Closed'
```

or this format

```
'Monday: Open 24 hours,Tuesday: Open 24 hours,Wednesday: Open 24 hours,Thursday: Open 24 hours,Friday: Open 24 hours,Saturday: Open 24 hours,Sunday: Open 24 hours'
```

And also be sure to take a look at [dateparser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some natural language date parser, for example [dateparser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser):

> dateparser provides modules to easily parse localized dates in almost
>   any string formats commonly found on web pages.
>
> - Generic parsing of dates in English, Spanish, Dutch, Russian and over 20 other languages plus numerous formats in a language agnostic
>     fashion.
> - Generic parsing of relative dates like: '1 min ago', '2 weeks ago', '3 months, 1 week and 1 day ago', 'in 2 days', 'tomorrow'.
> - Generic parsing of dates with time zones abbreviations or UTC offsets like: 'August 14, 2015 EST', 'July 4, 2013 PST', '21 July 2013
>     10:15 pm +0500'.
> - Support for non-Gregorian calendar systems. See Supported Calendars.
> - Extensive test coverage.

If you need to parse it, then as @asongtoruin proposed, you have to use regular expressions:

```
import re
opened_str = 'Monday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Tuesday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Wednesday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Thursday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Friday: 8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM,Saturday: Closed,Sunday: Closed'

PARSE_RE = re.compile(r'(?P<DAY>Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday): (?P<WORKHOURS>(?P<OPEN>\d+:\d+ (:?AM|PM)) \x96 (?P<CLOSE>\d+:\d+ (:?AM|PM))|Closed|Open 24 hours)')

for item in PARSE_RE.findall(opened_str):
    print(item)
```

Which will print:

```
('Monday', '8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', 'AM', '5:30 PM', 'PM')
('Tuesday', '8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', 'AM', '5:30 PM', 'PM')
('Wednesday', '8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', 'AM', '5:30 PM', 'PM')
('Thursday', '8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', 'AM', '5:30 PM', 'PM')
('Friday', '8:30 AM \x96 5:30 PM', '8:30 AM', 'AM', '5:30 PM', 'PM')
('Saturday', 'Closed', '', '', '', '')
('Sunday', 'Closed', '', '', '', '')
```

So you can check each tuple's *2nd* and *3rd* index for opened/closed times or *1st* if it's closed. After that you can parse those dates how you like.

Comment: so you are saying that i should parse the text first and then use date parser to convert it into timestamp and get the difference to find the weekly opening hours?

Comment: I had gone through it. It will not work for me. because i don't have dates i just have common week day timings.

Comment: @grundic.Thanks its working fine now for both cases.

Comment: @jarryjafery, awesome! You can accept the answer if it helped to solve your problem.